# Issue assigning setState with instance of an Object

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue with React-Native and i have been working on this for hours with no result. Appreciate your help.

I am passing an instance of a User Object to a child component through navigator Component in React-Native

So, i have defined my constructor as follows:

```
  constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     isSpinnerLoading: true,
     user : React.PropTypes.instanceOf(User).isRequired
   };
 }
```

i fill out my user object with its correspondent information and then i invoke this.props.navigator. Up to here everythings works perfect.

```
        this.props.navigator.replace({
           id: 'RegisterPage',
           passProps: {user: this.state.user}
        });
```

When i move to the RegisterPage Component inside of the componentWillMount() method i send an alert to check the information, everything looks good so far.

But when i create a new instance of the User object and fill out its details and want to setState as shown below, the information is not loading on the state

```
componentWillMount() {
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.props.user));

  let newUser = new User(this.props.user.getId,
  this.props.user.getFirstName,
  this.props.user.getLastName,
  this.props.user.getFullName,
  this.props.user.getProfilePicture,
  this.props.user.getEmail,
  this.props.user.getAlternativeEmail,
  this.props.user.getPassword,
  this.props.user.getRole,
  this.props.user.getAccessToken);

  this.setState({
     user : newUser
  });
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.user));

 }
```

I am getting undefined in the alert message. Could you please explain this behavior

Thank you so much for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

This means that you can't assume that `this.state.user` will be defined immediately after calling `setState`.

You can however use a callback to notify you when the state has been updated:

```
this.setState({
   user : newUser
}, function() {
   alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.user));
});
```

Comment: @Juve glad I could help :)